# Linux commands are hanging on ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

We are having a VPC setup for our staging environment. In this we have attached an elastic ip to one instance & rest of the instances are connected through this.

Now today when we restarted our machines we are facing trouble running commands like top, vi, ps etc.

Also we have noticed that if we connect to secondary machines via their public ip then everything is working fine. However if we connect via primary machine then the screen hangs after the command is issued.

Having a hard time debugging the root cause. Any suggestions will be quite helpful.

Comment: try running `top` (even if takes long time) to see what's on top), also stop some services, something is using all of resources..

Comment: It's not clear where your problem lies. Are you experiencing this problem on the primary system or on the secondary systems having previously connected to the primary (ssh ->primary then ssh secondary) 
?

Comment: @alexus Server is disconnected after sometime with time out error.

Comment: @Iain Any connection that is being made through primary server is experiencing this issue.

Comment: For others coming here, OP said the reason was his office network in this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266040/linux-commands-are-hanging-on-ec2-instance